# JavaSpark connection to Database

Tags: java, database, angular, apache-spark, connection

We are working on a project where we want to connect to a database via Java Spark. I have experience in the area of databases and frontend but I am a newcomer to Java Spark. I just want to know how to set up a connection and how to access a table.
We are using Angular4 and a SQL Database

I would be very happy if you could help me or show me a small example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
    options.put("url","jdbc:mysql://<DBURL>:<PORT>/<Database>?user=<UserName>&password=<Password>");
    options.put("dbtable", "<TableName>");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("DBConnection").setMaster("local[*]"));
    SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
    // DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", options).cache();
    DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.jdbc(options.get("url"),options.get("dbtable"));
    System.out.println("Data------------------->" + jdbcDF.toJSON().first());
    Row[] rows = jdbcDF.collect();
    System.out.println("Without Filter \n ------------------------------------------------- ");
    for (Row row2 : rows) {
        System.out.println(row2.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("Filter Data\n ------------------------------------------------- ");
    jdbcDF = jdbcDF.select("agency_id","route_id").where(jdbcDF.col("route_id").$less$eq(3));
    rows = jdbcDF.collect();
    for (Row row2 : rows) {
        System.out.println(row2.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Thank You! :)